# Как вызвать метод, при изменении значения переменной

Tags: c#

Мне нужно вызывать метод, при изменении значения какой либо переменной.
Я знаю самый простой способ - через property.

```
private int health;
public int Health
{
    get => health;
    set
    {
        health = value;

        //И тут вызывать метод.
    }
}
```

Но в таком случае, нужно строго использовать объявленный property Health.
Это не очень удобно, так как можно очень легко ошибится и использовать health вместо Health. Поэтому постоянно приходиться держать в голове, что нужно использовать Health.

Я считаю, что должен быть другой способ, попроще, который я не знаю, но надеюсь, что его знаете Вы!

Comment: Сделать healt private как и должно быть по принципам ООП.

Comment: @becouse а других способов нету?

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы путаете переменные. Вам привели пример, который вам не позволит путать переменные.

Comment: @becouse да, возможно используя _health я не буду путать переменные, но на мой взгляд это костыль

Comment: @NotGoodEnough Это не костыль, а принцип ООП. Сделав переменную private вы к ней просто не сможете обратиться вне класса. Даже если попробуете обратиться, то программа просто не скомпилируется, таким образом избежав ошибки.

Comment: @ГеннадийП под костылём я подрузомевал название переменной health используя _.

Comment: @NotGoodEnough, переменную не обязательно звать используя `_`

Comment: @NotGoodEnough Не важно как вы ее назовете(выделите префиксом, суффиксом или еще как), она из-за `private` в любом случае не будет доступна вне класса.

Answer (score 4):

```
private int _health;
public int Health {
  set { 
    if (value != _health) {
      _health = value;
      // call method
    }
  }
  get {
    return _health;
  }
}
```

Comment: Я точно такой же пример привёл выше... Он не удобный, есть ли другой способ?

Comment: @NotGoodEnough Ваш пример не компилируется. Мой пример - удобный, найдите пять отличий.

Comment: почему это мой пример не компилируется?

Comment: @NotGoodEnough Ваш пример немного не так работает как поставлено в ТЗ. Должно быть `при *изменении* значения`, а ваш при любой записи значения, даже того же самого.

Answer (score 1):

Другой вариант с событиями

```
class Person
{
    internal delegate void HealthEvent();
    public event HealthEvent OnHealthChanged; 
    private int _health;
    public int Health
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != _health)
            {
                _health = value;
                if (OnHealthChanged != null) OnHealthChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _health;
        }
    }

}
```

после создаете экземпляр класса

```
Person p = new Person();
```

и подписываете его на ваш метод, это может быть один или несколько методов

```
p.OnHealthChanged += InformIfHealthChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(value) 
{
   //do something

}
```

Если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: Если health принимает значение value то тогда вызвать метод?